# A strong Hausdorff condition

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Is the following strong form of Hausdorff equivalent to  usual Hausdorff?

> $X$ is *strong Hausdorff* if given distinct elements $x,y$ in $X$ there are open sets $U,V \subseteq X$ with $x \subseteq U$, $y \subseteq V$ and $\overline{U} \cap \overline{V} = \emptyset$.

I think that it is not equivalent, but haven't been able to prove this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this property is called being Urysohn (or sometimes *completely Hausdorff*), see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn_space). There we also find an example (from Steen and Seebach's book) of a Hausdorff but not Urysohn space: the relatively prime integer topology: [online explanation](http://planetmath.org/hausdorffspacenotcompletelyhausdorff).

Answer (score 7):

As Henno Brandsma's answer shows, this property is not equivalent to Hausdorffness.  Another example (of my own construction, though I highly doubt it is original) is as follows:

Let $X = ( \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z} ) \cup \{ -\infty , +\infty \}$.  For notational convenience, by $\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ I will denote the positive integers, and by $\mathbb{Z}^{<0}$ I will denote the negative integers.

We topologise $X$ as follows:

- each $\langle i,n \rangle$ with $n \neq 0$ is isolated.
- the basic open neighbourhoods of $\langle i,0 \rangle$ are of the form $\{ \langle i,0 \rangle \} \cup \{ \langle i,n \rangle : |n| \geq k \}$ for $k > 0$.
- the basic open neighbourhoods of $-\infty$ are of the form $\{ -\infty \} \cup A$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}^{<0}$ is such that $\{ i \in \mathbb{N} : \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}^{<0} : \langle i,n \rangle \notin A\text{ is infinite} \} \}$ is finite.
- the basic open neighbourhoods of $+\infty$ are of the form $\{ -\infty \} \cup A$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ is such that $\{ i \in \mathbb{N} : \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}^{>0} : \langle i,n \rangle \notin A\text{ is infinite} \} \}$ is finite.

(The basic idea is that the subspaces $( \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}^{<0} ) \cup \{ - \infty \}$ and $( \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}^{>0} ) \cup \{ +\infty \}$ are copies of the [Arens-Fort space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space), and each $\langle i,0\rangle$ is a limit point of the sections $\{ i \} \times \mathbb{Z}^{<0}$ and $\{ i \} \times \mathbb{Z}^{>0}$.)

It is fairly easy to show that $X$ is Hausdorff.

However, if $U$ and $V$ are (basic) open neighbourhoods of $-\infty$, $+\infty$, respectively, then there must be an $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{ n \in \mathbb{Z}^{<0} : \langle i,n \rangle \in U \}$ and $\{ n \in \mathbb{Z}^{>0} : \langle i,n \rangle \in V \}$ are both infinite, and so $\langle i,0 \rangle \in \overline{U} \cap \overline{V}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another example based on the examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83781/is-a-countable-totally-disconnected-hausdorff-space-necessarily-totally-separat). For each integer $n$, let $I_n$ denote the open interval $(n,n+1)$.

> Let $X = \mathbb{R} \cup \{p_0,p_1\}$, where $p_0$ and $p_1$ are distinct points not belonging to $\mathbb{R}$. Topologize $X$ by declaring $U \subseteq X$ to be open if and only if the following hold:
>
> - $U \cap \mathbb{R}$ is open with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$
> - If $p_0 \in U$, then $U$ contains all but finitely many of $I_0,I_2,I_4,\ldots$
> - If $p_1 \in U$, then $U$ contains all but finitely many of $I_1,I_3,I_5,\ldots$

This space is Hausdorff. However, if $U$ is an open neighbourhood of either $p_0$ or $q_0$, then $\overline U$ contains all but finitely many of the positive integers. Thus, neighbourhoods of $p$ and $q$ can never have disjoint closures.

Comment: You can also replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ and the $I_n$ by their rational counterparts to get an example $X$ that is also countable and totally disconnected (having only singleton connnected subsets). This is what is done under the link.