# Counterexample to "Urysohn Lemma for Hausdorff Spaces"

Tags: general-topology

Take a Hausdorff topological space $X$, and two distinct points $p,q \in X$.  Is there a continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(p) \neq f(q)$?

The answer is probably no, but I don't have a ready-made counterexample.  As soon as we add the adjective "compact" the space $X$ becomes normal, so that the Urysohn lemma applies, and it gives us such a function.

So the place to look is Hausdorff spaces that are not regular/normal.  However, the examples of these that I know are often constructed as finer topologies on the real line, and so come equipped with a ready made map to $\mathbb{R}$ that separates points.

Comment: Have you tried using the Deleted Tychonoff Plank? It is Hausdorff and not normal

Comment: @MTurgeon: The Deleted Tychonoff Plank is completely regular, and therefore completely Hausdorff, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Hausdorff space which is not [*completely Hausdorff*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn_and_completely_Hausdorff_spaces).

The examples provided as answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/784534/8348) would fit the bill. In particular, these Hausdorff spaces have the (stronger) property that there are distinct $x,y \in X$ such that $\overline{U} \cap \overline{V} \neq \varnothing$ for any open neighbourhoods $U,V$ of $x,y$, respectively.

Note that if $x \neq y$ can be separated by a continuous real-valued function $f : X \to [0,1]$ (*i.e.*, $f(x) = 0$ and $f(y) = 1$) then the neighbourhoods $f^{-1} [ [0,\frac{1}{3}) ]$ and $f^{-1} [ ( \frac{2}{3} , 1 ] ]$ must have disjoint closures.  (This is because for a continuous $f : X \to Y$ we must have that $\overline{f^{-1} [ B ]} \subseteq f^{-1} [ \overline{B} ]$ for all $B \subseteq Y$.)