# A‎ ‎regularly ‎closed ‎subset ‎of ‎an ‎H-closed ‎space ‎is ‎H-closed.

Tags: general-topology

A Hausdorff topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ is called *H-closed* or *absolutely closed*  if it is closed in any Hausdorff space which contains $X$ as a ‎subspace.‎
‎‎

**Remark:** ‎H-closedness ‎is ‎not ‎hereditary ‎with ‎respect ‎to ‎closed ‎subsets.‎
‎

**Theorem:** A‎ ‎regularly ‎closed ‎subset ‎of ‎an ‎H-closed ‎space ‎is ‎H-closed.

> What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a subset of an H-closed space to be H-closed?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a non-tautologous necessary and sufficient condition for general Hausdorff spaces, but for Urysohn spaces the problem is easier. The 'nice' Hausdorff spaces are all Urysohn, but the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784534/a-strong-hausdorff-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1) give examples of spaces which are Hausdorff but not Urysohn.

Here is a condition given in Proposition 3.2 (ii) in the paper [Closed Subspaces of H-Closed Spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102706674) by Johannes Vermeer.

> Let $X$ be an H-Closed Urysohn space. Then $A$ is an H-closed subspace
>   of $X$ iff $A$ is a compact subspace of $X_s$ and the restriction of
>   the map $\text{id}:X_s\rightarrow X$ to $A$ is $\theta$-continuous.

**Definitions**

A Urysohn space is a space in which any two distinct points have distinct closed neighbourhoods.

$X_s$ is the semiregularisation of $X$ i.e. the smallest space which contains $X$ whose regular open sets form a base.

A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is theta-continuous if for every $x\in X$ and neighbourhood $U$ of $f(x)$, there exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $f(\text{cl}(V))\subset \text{cl}(U)$.

Comment: My edit was to change $X_S$ to $X_s$ to conform with the notation in your statement of Vermeer's theorem. BTW, last week on this site I gave a complete answer to the Q: Prove that a Hausdorff space $X$ is H-closed iff  for every open cover $C$ of $X$ there exists a finite $D\subset C$ such that $\overline {\cup D}=X.$